# Angular 1.0 Application Not Indexing in Webmaster Tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, google-search-console

We have tried many solutions such as:

1. Submitting sitemaps
2. Using the deprecated escaped fragment code:
   `<meta name="fragment" content="!" />`
3. Pre-Rendering and routing to content via `userAgent` detection.

What is best practice for indexing a site test the indexing of a site in google as well as the best practices for other accessibility by 3rd party bots such as Facebook and other social `opengraph` tools?